# Is there a better way to calculate the semivariance of a list?

Tags: performance-tuning, function-construction

***edit2:***
The tweak suggested by *Henrik Schumacher* in *Carl Woll*'s answer is so far a clear winner ($\times800$ over the benchmark); it's almost disturbing to contemplate how '*slow*'-relatively speaking-something like `-(list - center)` is...

***edit1:***

So far this is the best alternative (without compiling anything yet)

```
negativeSemivariance5 = Function[{list, center, length}, 
  Total[Ramp[-(list - center)]^2]/(length - 1)
 ]
```

Evaluating the testing code snippet (simply replace `negativeSemivariance4` with `negativeSemivariance5`) returns

> ```
> {190., True}
> ```

which indicates a $\times190$ improvement on the specified test case.

---

***original:***

Is there a better way to write a [semivariance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chebyshev%27s_inequality#Semivariances) function?

This is my benchmark definition

```
negativeSemivariance0[list_, center_, length_] := Module[{sum = 0.},
   Scan[If[# < center, sum += (# - center)^2] &, list];
   sum/length
  ]
```

and this is the best version I can think of

```
negativeSemivariance4[list_, center_, length_] := 
 With[{first = First[list]},
  Fold[
    With[{d = center - #2},
      #1 + Ramp[d]^2
      ] &,
    Ramp[center - first]^2,
    Rest[list]
    ]/length
  ]
```

I use the following code for testing:

```
Through[{Divide @@ Part[#, All, 1] &, Equal @@ Part[#, All, -1] &}[BlockRandom[
 With[{n = 5000},
  With[{rand = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, n]},
   With[{mean = Mean[rand]},
    {negativeSemivariance0[rand, mean, n] // RepeatedTiming, 
     negativeSemivariance4[rand, mean, n] // RepeatedTiming}
    ]
   ]
  ], RandomSeeding -> 132456987]]]
```

Evaluating it, returns

> ```
> {20., True}
> ```

which can be interpreted as saying that the second version is $\times 20$ faster than the first and both functions return the same result.

Ps.This function will be frequently called on many different lists of same length. The size of the list used for testing-`n=5000`-is an average problem instance size.

Answer (score 2):

I think using [`Dot`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Dot) should provide a speed boost:

```
svariance = Function[{list, center, length}, 
    #.#&[Ramp[-(list - center)]]/(length - 1)
];
```

Comparison:

```
data = RandomReal[{-1,1}, 10^6];

svariance[data, .1, 10^6-1] //RepeatedTiming
negativeSemivariance5[data, .1, 10^6-1] //RepeatedTiming
```

> {0.0026, 0.222223}
>
> {0.0050, 0.222223}

Comment: `Function[{list, center, 
  length}, #.# &[Ramp[Subtract[center, list]]]/(length - 1)]` seems to be even a tick faster.

Answer (score 1):

```
Variance[Select[data, # < Mean[data] &]]
```

Comment: `Variance[]` uses `Mean[Select[]]` which is not the same as `Mean[data]`; the denominator used for calculating variance is `Length[Select[]]-1` instead of `Length[data]-1`

Answer (score 1):

Replacing `Ramp[-(list-center)]` with `Ramp[Subtract[center,list]]` in @Carl's version seems to give a slight improvement in timings. Also, if the third argument `length` can be taken as the length of the input list, you can take the second [Moment](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Moment.html) of the clipped list to get timings better than `negativeSemivariance5`.

```
semivar = Function[{list, center, length}, #.#&@Ramp[Subtract[center, list]]/(length-1)];
moment1 = Function[{list, center}, 
   MomentEvaluate[Moment[2], Ramp[Subtract[center, list]]]]; 
 moment2 = Function[{list, center}, Moment[Ramp[Subtract[center, list] ], 2]];
```

**Timings:**

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 10^6]; 
{RepeatedTiming @ semivar[data, .1, 10^6 ] , 
 RepeatedTiming @ svariance[data, .1, 10^6 ] ,
 RepeatedTiming @ moment1[data, .1 ] ,  
 RepeatedTiming @ moment2[data, .1 ] ,   
 RepeatedTiming @ negativeSemivariance5[data, .1, 10^6 ]}
```

> {{0.0017, 0.222018}, {0.0021, 0.222018}, {0.055, 0.222017}, {0.0061, 0.222017},
>     {0.0066, 0.222018}}

Comment: yes indeed `length` is equal to the length of `list`; the tweak in `Ramp` is actually the one with the best performance so far; I was totally oblivious about the performance gains obtainable with `Moment` (needs a slight correction by a factor `n/(n - 1)`; it performs slightly worse than `negativeSemivariance5` but it definitely is an  improvement over the benchmark)